# Commutator of the Hamiltonian and Parity Operator - evaluation of derivatives

Tags: derivatives, quantum-mechanics

I was studying the commutator of the Hamiltonian and parity operators in the $L^2$ space from Quantum mechanics and came upon the following:

To show that the two operators commute, assuming we have a symmetric potential $V(x)=V(-x)$, we had that the commutator of a function $\psi(x)$ was;

\begin{align*}[\hat{H},\hat{P}]=&-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\psi(-x)+V(x)\psi(-x)+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial (-x)^2}\psi(-x)-V(-x)\psi(-x)\\=&-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\psi(-x)+\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial (-x)^2}\psi(-x),
\end{align*}

assuming the symmetry of the potential $V(x)$.

Now I struggled to show that the two second derivative terms are the negative of each other. The only possible way I could deduce the were equal was by using the chain rule for the second partial derivative to deduce that:

$$\frac{\partial \psi(-x)}{\partial (-x)}=\frac{\partial \psi(-x)}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial (-x)}=-\frac{\partial \psi(-x)}{\partial x},$$ and hence the partial derivative terms both cancel out to show the operators commute.

Now my main issue is struggling with the derivatives, could this be clarified?

As an aside I also had thought about the Lagrange and Leibniz notation, and was wondering whether the following was incorrect or not?

$$\frac{\partial \psi(-x)}{\partial x}=-\psi '(-x) \,\text{ and }\, \frac{\partial \psi(-x)}{\partial (-x)}=\psi'(-x).$$

Comment: The chain rule you applied is correct.

Comment: @Berci do you have any idea on the last part of the post?

Comment: Yes, that's correct too. Note that for any $u=u(x)$ we have $\frac{\partial f(u)}{\partial u}=f'(u)$.

Comment: I think I figured out the issue I was having with the derivatives ! If we apply the operators in the necessary order then it all sorts itself out... the main issue I was getting confused with was whether to differentiate the function first or evaluate it at $-x$, but this can be dealt with by carefully applying the operators correctly. As an example if $f(x)=x+x^2$ then differentiating first and evaluating at $-x$ gives $f'(-x)=1-2x$ whereas doing so in the reverse order gives $f'(-x)=-1+2x$ and so the order in which we apply these operations was the matter of my confusion.